# Rails: HTTP version for response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers

If someone POSTs to my Rails application with HTTP version 1.0 like this:

```
POST /update HTTP/1.0
```

How do I send an HTTP version 1.0 response like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3. Rails responses always seem to be HTTP version 1.1, but if the client sends a request with HTTP version 1.0 I want to respond with HTTP version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your controller to build Header-only responses, you can use the `head` method. Example:

```
head :bad_request
```

Would produce the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2010 12:15:53 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Runtime: 0.013483
Set-Cookie: _blog_session=...snip...; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

[More information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)

Comment: This doesn't help me to change the HTTP version of the response.

Comment: Why would you want to change the HTTP version? I guess you just want to send another status code, which is exactly what `head` does. If this is not what you are looking for, make your question more clear.

Comment: I want the HTTP version of the response to be the same as that of the request.

Comment: I see. Never thought about that. Don't know if such thing is built right into Rails.

Comment: if you can't find a way in rails (which would be surprising if there is a use for doing so) you could consider rack middleware to modify the response once it leaves rails